# Prevent parent page from scrolling down to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have embedded a website using iframe. Whenever the parent page loads, the embedded page makes the parent page scroll down to the iframe. I cannot change any code in the embedded page, I have only access to the parent page. Here's the [fiddle of the issue:](http://jsfiddle.net/ygz61zr2/)

HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://store4549118.ecwid.com/#!/~/cart" width="100%" height="100%" id="Container"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin-top: 100px; height: 1000px; }
```

How can I prevent the parent page from scrolling down to the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using the wrong ID value for the your `iframe`.

Swap `container` for `asContainer` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Please take a look at the issue fiddle. I don't want to load the other quesntion's page, but the one in the issue fiddle. the parent page scrolls down to the iframe, I'd like to stay at the top of the parent page.

Comment: My suggestion is for making the solution with JQuery to work. You need to change the ID value to match the ID value used in the JQuery function you included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygz61zr2/3/) with a working copy.  You also did not have jquery loaded so make sure if you want to use jquery that you are loading it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Container').attr("src", "//audio-surf.com/mypage.php?u=DJDavid98#favorites_container").on('load', function() {
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for helping. The page I want to load is this one (http://store4549118.ecwid.com/#!/~/cart) (not the audio-surf used in the other question's example); when loading, the parent is still scrolling down.

Comment: Thanks but I need this page to load (http://store4549118.ecwid.com/#!/~/cart), not this (http://store4549118.ecwid.com/#23!/~/cart).
I need the cart page to load, and the page is forcing the bar to scroll down to iframe's position.

Comment: sorry I was supposed to replace the # with %23 but can see that that does not work also.